# JavaScript how to send different entities but keeping the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, dom

Suppose I have 2 areas separated by div containers, I need to send the Id values from the different areas, locally when the function is called in that container.

extract:

```
   <script> 
       document.getElementById('compare_name").innerHTML = "Changed";
</script>

<div class = "details>

    <span id="compare_name">no1</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>

<div class  = "details">

<span id="compare_name">no2</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have same IDs, IDs are meant to be **unique**

Comment: can you explain what you try do?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use same ID for more than one element. you can use name instead like below:

```
<script> 
       var x = document.getElementsByName("compare_name");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
x[i].innerHTML = "Changed";
                        }
</script>

<div class = "details>

    <span id="compare_name" name="compare_name">no1</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>

<div class  = "details">

<span id="compare_name" name="compare_name">no2</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your forms have duplicate IDs.

Comment: @maxcal I used the same HTML which OP provided however I mentioned name for the html element for which OP wanted to change the content

Comment: Sorry missed that, I would fix it and add a code comment though.

Comment: What does lead means @AshwinRamesh

Answer (score 1):

As others indicates that, to follow the rule, the ID attribute should not be duplicated, but it doesn't matter if you don't rely on it.

I guess the asker might only need to change one text inside the div which is clicked, not all the spans, so just a little change.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
function add_compare(el) {
    var divChildEles = el.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i<divChildEles.length; i++) {
        if (divChildEles[i].nodeType==1 && divChildEles[i].nodeName=="SPAN") {
            //console.log(divChildEles[i].innerText);
            divChildEles[i].innerText='changed';
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "details">
    <span id="compare_name">no1</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare(this)">
    </form>
</div>

<div class  = "details">
    <span id="compare_name">no2</span> 
    <form id="view-details1">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare(this)">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

id in JavaScript must be unique. instead, you can give them a class with the same name

```
<script> 
       var x=document.getElementByClassName('compare_name");
        for(var i=0;i<x.lengh;i++)
           x[i].innerHTML = "Changed"
</script>

<div class = "details>

    <span class="compare_name">no1</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>

<div class  = "details">

<span class="compare_name">no2</span> 
    <form id="view-details0">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The ID is a HTML attribute. It does not really have anything to do with javascript except for the browsers pretty stupid arcane behavior of creating globals for elements with ids.